# Laravel factory - What's the difference between create and make

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code:

```
$this->actingAs(factory('App\User')->create());

$thread = factory('App\Thread')->make();
```

what is the difference between create() and make() and why is it not listed in the helper functions page in the Laravel documentation?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`create` persists to the database while `make` just creates a new instance of the model.

> the `make` method to create models without persisting them to the database

> The `create` method instantiates model instances and persists them to the database using Eloquent's save method

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories#instantiating-models

If you'd like to see the source code differences between make and create you can see them in [`framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php#L270)

Answer (score 3):

```
Laravel create method is created the model instance and save data in the database.
Make function has created the instance of the class.
```

[click here for more info](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#using-factories)